# How to use KeyListener to capture ONLY when the key has been pressed

Tags: java, keyboard, awt

I know how the KeyListener works, however the problem is that the abstract method KeyPressed doesn't works as I expect. 
Instead of calling the function each key press, calls the function all the time the key is being pressed.
Is it possible to handle **only** when I press the key and not when its being pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement KeyListener and override keyPressed. Set a value that is kept until keyReleased is invoked.